# Get the multidimensional array index value corresponding to other array values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've a PHP multidimensional array like:

```
array(
    [0] => array("code"=>code1, "value"=>val1, "operation"=>Add),
    [1] => array("code"=>code2, "value"=>val2, "operation"=>Remove),
    [2] => array("code"=>code3, "value"=>val3, "operation"=>Edit)
)
```

If I know `code` and `value`, how can I get the `operation` array index value corresponding to that entry. Eg: If I pass *code1* and *val1*, then it should return the value *Add*. I can use `foreach()`, but I'm looking for some other faster and efficient way to get it.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no faster and efficient way.

Comment: Do you get the structure like that from an endpoint, or do you build it somewhere?

Comment: Are there dupicate entries for `code`, `value` or `operation` possible in the array?

Comment: @PhilippMaurer. No. Duplicate entries are not possible and I'm constructing this array using jquery and passing to php page.

Answer (score 2):

Simple `foreach` with a `break`/`return` when found will be `O(n)` in worst case, `O(1)` in best.

Modifying source array as:

```
array(
    'code1:val1' => Add,
    'code2:val2' => Remove,
    'code3:val3' => Edit
)
```

will give you `O(1)` with accessing like `$arr['code1:val1']`.

Solution, for example, with `array_filter` will be `O(n)` **always**.

Comment: Additional information: The reason that *"Solutions, for example, with `array_filter` will be `O(n)` __always__."* is, that the data-structure you (question author) built in the first place is handling all information as values. Therefore it is not optimized for a search in any way. This solution is an optimal solution, because the search relevant information are used as keys instead, so they can be used in a search.

Answer (score 0):

just run a foreach. It will be an O(n) search on worst case.

```
function getOperation($code,$value){
    foreach($array as $key => $item){
        if($item["code"]===$code && $item["value"] === $value)
            return $item["operation"];
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: The question author wrote: *" I can use `foreach()`, but I'm looking for some other faster and efficient way to get it."* Therefore your answer is not an answer.

Comment: okay, I understand you. I think I addressed that however on the first line that say "just run a foreach". Nothing is gonna be faster than that. The code fragment was just an overkill in case someone else would need the fragment. I wasn't looking forward to make my contribution the correct answer for the question but rather a universal solution for anybody else who would find themself in such a scenario. Thank you though for flagging it the right way. It's not a solution to the given question.